# Poker aggression - Flop, Turn and River

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy, poker-stars

Given a low stakes NL Holdem game, statistics of 200+ hands are given as below.

PreFlop aggression :  60%

Flop aggression    :  70%

Turn aggression    :  50%

River aggression   :  66%

Win rate           :  45%

What are the shortcomings of playing style with above stats? Is winning on river card bad? Do player have to win before river round?

Comment: Would also be great to see preflop %, but from a glance I'd say with that level of aggression you'll be extremely open to being taken advantage from trapping by anyone paying attention

Comment: Pre-flop Aggr: 60%

Comment: So one more question for clarification, by aggression you mean hands you're playing and raising, or are you including all hands you've decided to play? As in if you're playing say 10% of hands and being aggressive preflop 60% of the time, which is a big difference than playing 60% of all hands preflop and being aggressive with them.

Comment: VPIP and PFR are less than 25

Comment: I understand what is AFq (agression frequency) but given the figures I'm almost certain you're not speaking of the same stat. What are your statistics and how are they calculated ? Also, it's important to note that 200 hands is a very low sample statistically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

"PreFlop aggression : 60%"
If it is not a heads up (1 on 1) but 6 or more seats poker than it is too much. It is almost impossible on a long run play profitable with such preflop aggression. Especially playing as aggressive on a postflop streets.

It is not clear what do you mean by "win rate". Do you mean that you win 60% of hands where you put voluntary in pot? If so it doesn't matter much comparing to average % of winning in big blinds per hand. The value of avg win can be negative. Avg win 0.10 (10% of a big blind per game) is a very good result.